# Cómo enlazar dos Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-html-service

Realice dos web con Apps Script de Google. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para insertar uno dentro del otro? Usé el `<iframe src="...."></iframe>` pero no se muestra se esa parte se queda en plomo con el mensaje script Google rechazo la conexión

el get en ambos es

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("exitoso");
}
```

script  prueba

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    hola como estas
  </body>
</html>
```

script exitoso

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    exitoso
    <iframe src="https://script.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/exec" title="exito"></iframe>
  <script>
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En la aplicación web que va a ser insertada tienes que modificar la función `doGet` para incluir el modo sandbox a utilizar (`HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL`)

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("exitoso")
    .evaluate()
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setXFrameOptionsMode(XFrameOptionsMode)
- [Embedding Google Apps Script in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40842627/1595451)
- [App Script HTMLService App in iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16808722/1595451)